# Send modbus rtu command directly to client without using Virtual Comport

Tags: c#, tcp, serial-port, modbus

I'm doing a system that gathers information from sensors and receive information sent by them through USR DTU.

For now, I have succeeded configuring the sensors - DTU & server connection through TCP/IP.
However, my old program can only read & write data through COM Port.
That's why I have to use Virtual COM Port software to make a bridge between Server program (which uses COM Port) & USR DTU through TCP/IP Connection.

[image]

My question is: **Can I send the command (which is modbus rtu protocol) through TCP/IP Connection directly without help of Virtual COM Port software ? I want to do this because virtual com port software only allows me to create 255 ports and that is not enough to me.**

Answer (score 0):

> Can I send the command (which is modbus rtu protocol) through TCP/IP
>   Connection directly without help of Virtual COM Port software

It looks like you are using a [USR-GPRS232-730](https://www.usriot.com/products/rs232-gsm-modem.html) and these units have a "Transparent Mode". With that mode enabled anything sent via the TCP/IP link is retransmitted over the serial link and vice versa. So long as that is the case then the answer is yes it is possible to transmit Modbus RTU commands over the link without using a virtual com port. I use this technique (with different GPRS units) to poll a range of remote RTU devices.

> I want to do this because virtual com port software only allows me to
>   create 255 ports and that is not enough to me

Therein lies the problem; if your software only supports local ports then you need to provide it with a local port (which is what the Virtual Com Port software does). Your question is not clear on whether you are considering replacing your "old program" or what the software is, what OS you are using etc.

Comment: When I tried sending Modbus RTU command directly from my app to sensor through DTU, my sensor did not reply. With the same command, when I sent through Virtual COM Port software, the sensor replied. Should I include any further information in the request from server (TCP/IP)

Comment: When using this setup you establish the TCP link and then send/expect to receive exactly the same data as you would using a serial link. Does your app work when connected to the sensor via a serial link?

Comment: One other thought - have you set the baud rate etc via the web interface. The virtual serial port app pobably does this automatically (looks like you can also do this by sending [a specific string](https://www.usriot.com/support/faq/653.html) to the DTU).

Comment: I think your opinion is similar to my thought. In my opinion, I think Virtual com port software has alternated some bytes or data before sending my message to designated TCP/IP endpoint. I'm still searching for a solution that I can send my modbus rtu frame directly to TCP/IP endpoint, however, for the current situation, I have to keep using Virtual COM Port software.

Comment: The Virtual Comm port software should not alter any of the bytes being sent (and you would not want it to). With your solution if the baud rate (and data bits/parity/stop bits) is not set correctly then the solution will not work (as mentioned you can edit that via the web interface). Other than that what you are trying to do should work (as mentioned previously I use this technique for quite a number of different remote devices albeit with a different DTU). Good luck!